# Factory static methods and private constructors

Tags: php, singleton, static-methods

I have an class `Foo` and a class `Bar` and I want to utilize `Bar`'s static methods to get a singleton instance of `Foo`, (similar to the way `BitmapFactory.create()` returns a `Bitmap` instance), BUT `Foo` should not be instanced using `new Foo()`, how do I get that?

```
class Foo {
    $private Foo() {} // ??
}

class Bar {
    private static $foo = null;
    static function getFooInstance() {
         if(Bar::$foo == null) $foo = new Foo();               
         return Bar::$foo;
    }
} 



$foo = Bar::getFooInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

The what you want to do is make `Foo` a singleton and make `Bar` assign to bar by  `Foo::getInstance();` For example:

```
class Foo {
    private static $instance;
    private function __construct(){}
    public static function getInstance(){
        if (!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new Foo();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function __clone(){
        throw new Exception("Cannot Clone Singletons... bad programmer");
    }
}

class Bar {
    static function getFooInstance() {
         return Foo::getInstance();
    }
}
```

There is no need to replay the singleton pattern within Bar as Foo already polices it's own instantiation.

Comment: 1) Instead of `self::$instace = new Foo()` you could it define it as, `self::$instance = new self()` 2) You could adhere to the DRY principle here, just like: `$i =& self::$instance; if (is_null($i)){  $i = new self();} return $i;`

Comment: @DaveJust you don't gain anything by doing that though....It will always return a `Foo` ... you would have to use `static` instead of `self` for it to mean anything different (Like a subclass of foo).

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to use a singleton pattern here. The singleton is a bad pattern and should be avoided.

The best solution is: Make a static factory method in `Bar` that guarantees that there will be only one `Foo` created. You already did that.

And for `Foo`: Simply do not instantiate it on it's own in your productive code. But you really want to instantiate several copys of `Foo` in your tests! Because of that you cannot make the constructor of `Foo` non-public.

Objects that usually are only created once should play an important part in your application. They will most likely be created once at the start and then used for several things. Create a dedicated factory class for this (or maybe one per topic: for models, for database and for templates). Make it a habit to only use these factories to create objects.

Or even better, add this to your Dependency Injection framework as a configuration. Usage when getting the objects is basically the same.